# Using Matplotlib object oriented interface to plot a bar chart from a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to draw a bar plot from a data frame using [Matplotlib object-oriented interface](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/api/agg_oo_sgskip.html). As far as I understand, Matplotlib `axe.bar` method only accept two arguments, `x` and `height`. Do I need to manually extract the data from the data frame, which seems to be very inefficient for a complex chart, or is there a more straightforward approach? For example, is there a way to use `df.plot(kind='bar')` method along with Matplotlib `axe` object?

Comment: Do you mean `df.plot(kind="bar", ax=axe)`?

Comment: Yes, df.plot(kind="bar").

Comment: So the answer is by adding `, ax=axe`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks a lot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, this might sound silly, but is there an "efficient" way to handle data frame with Matplotlib native methods?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "efficient way" and "handle". Feel free to edit your question to give some context and a clear problem description.